# Android AndEngine LeadBolt integration

Tags: android, notifications, andengine, ads, leadbolt

I just finished my android app and I want to try LeadBolt ads.

LeadBolt information:
[image]

Java code:

```
    @Override
public void onLoadComplete() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    myController = new AdController(this, "169901169");
    myController.loadAd();

}
```

LeadBolt notification isn't shown. Why?!

Answer (score 0):

You are running notifications, but in your code you have the following lines :
myController = new AdController(this, "169901169");
myController.loadAd();

Please change them to (as mentioned in the PDF documentation):
myController = new AdController(getApplicationContext(), "169901169");
myController.loadNotification();

The notification ads should then be working correctly.

Comment: I changed:   
myController = new AdController(getApplicationContext(),"169901169");
myController.setAsynchTask(true);
myController.loadNotification();

but does not work :(

Answer (score 0):

Notifications requires more operations. First of all, change Manifest, then follow LeadBolt documantation